# MySQL Workbench create table generates SQL that throws an error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL version 5.7.18 and MySQL Workbench is targeting version 5.6.20. However, when I try and create a table using the table generator it produces the following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `sys`.`annotations` (
  `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () VIRTUAL,
  `annotation` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

But this produces the following error message:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') STORED',
   `annotation` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`))' at line 2
 SQL Statement:
 CREATE TABLE `sys`.`annotations` (
   `id` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS () STORED,
   `annotation` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Why would this be happening and how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what an empty expression means for a computed column.  Nor do I understand a `VIRTUAL` column being a primary key.  I would use:

```
CREATE TABLE sys.`annotations` (
  `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `annotation` LONGTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: So the virtual is one of the following: virtual or stored, and seems to be the storage method of that column. I used generated because I didn't want the keys to be guaranteed to be neighbours.

Comment: @SebastianMalton . . . I think `auto_incremented` is much simpler for arriving at this solution.  You want the primary key value to be stored with the record, so virtual doesn't make sense to me (if it is allowed, then it will be materialized anyway).

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks for this note however even if I have the generated key being "stored" the same error occurred. I resolved to just use an incremental key but I point still stands that just installing MySQL and the workbench with the installer should not lead to the workbench not being able to generate statements that will always work.